# Hibernate materialize view, embedded two Entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have a question about Hibernate.

I have an Entity Panier:

```
@ Entity
public class Panier implements Serializable
{
     @ Id @ GeneratedValue
     private long idPanier;
     @ OneToOne
     private Client client;
     @ OneToMany
     private List items = new ArrayList <LignePanier> <LignePanier> ();
     private int nbArticle;
     private double subtotal;
     private double vat;
     private double totalTtc;
     ...
}
```

So I create a table that contains my data with a relationship with my lines of the Panier (Article + quantity).

Now I'd like to have a mechanism to store the invoice created from the Panier. But that is made ​​of a static snapshot, because the bill does not update itself if the price of an item has changed.

So I'd like to know what the right strategy to applied with hibernate.

I create an Entity Invoice but I would like it to store all in the same table without foreign key reference.

```
@ Entity
@ Immutable
public class Invoice implements Serializable
{
     @ Id @ GeneratedValue
     private long idFacture;
     private Date OrderDate;
     private String moyenPayement;
     @ Embedded
     private Panier panier;
     ...
}
```

I wanted to use the Embedded annotation which seems to do what i want. But the problem is that this is only applicable to an object @Embeddable annotations and not @Entity. The two do not coexist together.

So how can we / should we do.

I'am using PostgreSQL as database.

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Pirlot Nicolas

Answer (score 1):

If you use entityManager.merge() to save or update Panier then not only will your entity update or get inserted but also any entity that it contains. Just make sure that each of the embded entities have id's. Lose the @Embedded annotation.

If the embded entities do not have id's then new ones will be created.